# Python - read numbers from text file in a function

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to write a program that ensures to write on a text file finding prime numbers between given number and limit. If the number exists in file, It tries to write another number which is coprime with the given(entered) number. Then it is written on the text file. **My problem is checking numbers from text file whether exist or not. How can I write it ?** So, I have researched since the morning but, I can't find helpful answers for the problem. I think Python quite a change works from C.

Example: entered number is 12 and limit is 3

generated numbers are 1,5,7

second running 1,5,7 exist on the text file than generates 11,13,17 and print them.

```
def coprime(x,y):
    """Returns True if the number is copime
    else False."""
    if x % y == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True


"""

def text_file() function will be here
if number searching number exists on the text file return True
else return False


"""

f = open("numbers.txt","a+")
i = 0
j = 0

num = int(raw_input("Please enter number "))
limit = int(raw_input("Please enter limit "))

while i < limit:
    if text_check(file,j) == False and coprime(num,j) == True:
        f.write(str(j))
        i += 1
        j += 1
        print "%d is written on the text file" % j 

    else:
        j += 1

f.close()
```

Comment: You need to put `a+` in quote `'a+'`. and whats the problem now ?

Comment: how are you writing the numbers to file?

Comment: using `file_write(str(j))`. I read that numbers cannot be written directly. They must be converted to string using `str()` ? Am I wrong ? @PadraicCunningham

Comment: yes but are you writing one big line or are you delimiting them some way

Comment: also in coprime `return x % y == 0` will suffice, that will either return True or False

Comment: you need to use `file.write(str(j))` , change `_` with `.`

Comment: it is simple program. There is no newline. Maximum 100 numbers will be at first line. So, it is one line. It is my idea maybe i am wrong.

Comment: I think a smarter way to go would be to add all the numbers to a set and check if the number exists in the set instead of the file

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Not to make fun But check this [tweet](https://twitter.com/mariofusco/status/542278747941261313)

Comment: Bad idea to use the name `file`, you are redefining a built-in (`file` is an alias for `open` in Python 2).  Personally I find Python much easier and logical than C, and I have been coding in C since the early 1980s.

Comment: i changed `file` to `f`. Then , What is your advise for the problem ? @cdarke

Comment: Personally I would use a `set`, like @PadraicCunningham suggested.  If the set of numbers is loo large to fit into memory, then consider a `shelve`.

Comment: BTW, your coprime function doesn't work if x > y, eg, x=15, y=5. x%y != 0, but x & y aren't coprime. Also, you need to delimit (separate) the numbers you write to the text file. Using newline is the most convenient, so you can easily view the file with other tools, but you could also use a space or comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

presuming all nums are all on separate lines like below:

```
1
5
7



from fractions import gcd

def coprime(n1, n2):
    return gcd(n1, n2) == 1 # same as if gcd(n1, n2) == 1:return True else: return False



with open("out.txt","a+") as f: # with automatically closes your files
    # add all previous numbers into a set, casting to int using map 
    # map(int, f)  equivalent to [int(ele) for ele in f] in python2
    nums_set = set(map(int, f)) # with 1 5 and 7 in the file nums_set = set([1, 5, 7])
    i = 0
    j = 0

    num = int(raw_input("Please enter number "))
    limit = int(raw_input("Please enter limit "))

    while i < limit:
        if j not in nums_set and coprime(num,j):
            f.write("{}\n".format(j))
            print "{} is written on the text file.".format(j)
            i += 1
            j += 1
            # add current j's from this run to the set to avoid reopening and rechecking he file        
            nums_set.add(j)       
        else:
            j += 1
```

Comment: thank you. But, I want to learn map ? I have some information about set now.

Comment: `map(int,f)` is equivalent to `[int(ele) for ele in f]`